# Angular - Add form values from a FormBuilder Form.group into a Map data structure

Tags: dictionary, hashmap, formgroups, angular2-formbuilder, angular-maps

I have a **FormBuilder** form group called **AddStatusBoxForm:**

```
AddStatusBoxForm = this.Form.group({
    name: ['']
  });
```

I then have a **Map** data structure which I think would have a type of **Map<string, string>:**

```
statusBoxValues = new Map<string, string>
  ([
    ['name', this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('name')?.value]
  ]);
```

The **Map** data structure takes in `this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('name')?.value` as the item in the map, with the key being the string **'name'**.

I test a few things with `console.log()`. First I print out the type of the value retrieved from the **AddStatusBoxForm** which returns a type of **string**. Then I print out the actual value of the input in the form which returns that same value. Lastly I attempt to print out the first item in my **statusBoxValues Map**, which contains the same code used to retrieve values from the **AddStatusBoxForm form group**. However this returns **empty string**, when I expect it to return the value that was inputted into the form.

```
console.log(typeof(this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('name')?.value)) //returns string
console.log(this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('name')?.value) // returns value of input 
console.log(this.statusBoxValues.get('name')) // returns <empty string>
```

[image]

Would anyone be able to help me so that I could add the values from a **Form Group** into a **Map** data structure, or maybe an equalivant data strucuture that has key pair values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('name')?.value` is firing, once and only once as you add it to the map.

Try this instead:

```
var statusBoxValues = {
  'name': () => this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('name')?.value,
  'otherName': () => this.AddStatusBoxForm.get('otherName')?.value,
};
```

You can then call the function like this:

```
this.statusBoxValues['name']();
```